# Print first three characters from six lines using Scala

Tags: scala

In a text file the characters are written like this:

**Input**

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I want the output like this using Scala:

**Output**

```
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It is very clear

Comment: "I want the output like this using Scala" – You could get it by writing a program in Scala which does what you want. If you encounter a problem with this program you have written, you carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, single-step through the code in a debugger, write tests, trace the execution with pen&paper, and if you still can't figure out the problem … wait a week or so and then start from the top with fresh eyes and a fresh mind.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice before using Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
import scala.io.Source
val lines = Source.fromFile("C:\\spark\\programs\\strings.txt").getLines.toList
val output=lines.grouped(3).map(_.mkString).mkString("\n")

//Sample Output: 
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: Can you provide me some links, where from I can learn about small usecases in scala? @Manoj

Comment: You can find most of the scala things here- https://alvinalexander.com/

Comment: Thanks! Now if I want to use `zipWithIndex` over here to achieve the same output  then how is it possible?

Comment: Do you also want to group indexes? Or what output you want?

Answer (score 3):

File `fileABC.txt` is supposed to be in current directory of `scala`.

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromFile("fileABC.txt").getLines.
             reduceLeft(_+_).grouped(3).foreach(println)

ABC
DEF
```

**OR**

```
scala>scala.io.Source.fromFile("fileABC.txt").getLines.mkString.grouped(3).foreach(println)
    ABC
    DEF
```

Comment: Thanks! Now if I want to use `zipWithIndex` over here to achieve the same output  then how is it possible?

Comment: Then it can be  a round-about method of doing the same thing in more steps with no extra benefit /convenience. `scala.io.Source.fromFile("fileABC.txt").getLines.mkString.grouped(3).toList.zipWithIndex.map(_._1).foreach(println)`